# ListView Not Stretching to Flyout in Placement.Full

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I'm Building a Win 10 UWP app. I have a `ListView` as per the below xaml, which is the content of a `Button.Flyout`. It is essentially the same as the standard `ListView` control, but provides a way for me to bind to the `IsSelected` property of the particular item. I've added the implementation for completeness. When `MinWindowWitdth` is 720, the placement mode is changed to `Right`. Whilst in this state, the `ListViewItem` stretches to fill the `ListView`. When not in this state (default), it is in `Placement.Full`, and the `ListViewItem` doesn't stretch to the entire `ListView`, which does seem to stretch to fill of the `Flyout`, as the `VerticalScrollBar` is visible against the right hand edge of the `Flyout`.

From what I could investigate, setting the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` with `HorizontalContentAlignment.Stretch` should have achieved the outcome, however I am left with content that only stretches about half way across and I can't figure out why.

I notice that he `CommandBar` is included in the scrollable content in the full screen `Flyout`, however, when in `Placement.Right` it is not (which is the intended design). So it appears that `Full` is causing the `Flyout` to create a `ScrollViewer` and disregard the `ListView.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch` property. Is there a way to get around this?

xaml;

```
<Button.Flyout>
                                <Flyout x:Name="RulesListFlyout" Placement="Full">
                                    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <commontools:ListViewWithSelectedItems x:Name="RulesListForInclusion" ItemsSource="{Binding AllRulesForInclusion}" SelectionMode="Multiple" IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="True"
                                                   RelativePanel.Above="RulesCommandB" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                                </Style>
                                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="ListViewItem">
                                                    <RelativePanel Margin="12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding StoredDataObject.Title}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                                                                   RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
                                                        <TextBox x:Name="Variable" Text="{Binding InputVariable, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="50" AcceptsReturn="False" RelativePanel.Below="Title"
                                                                 Visibility="{Binding ShowVariableBox, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVis}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                                    </RelativePanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </commontools:ListViewWithSelectedItems>
                                        <CommandBar x:Name="RulesCommandB" Grid.Row="1" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
                                            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Accept" Command="{Binding CommandSetIncludedRules}" Click="SetSpecialRuleFlyoutButton_Click"/>
                                            <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" Label="Cancel" Command="{Binding CommandResetIncludedRules}" Click="SetSpecialRuleFlyoutButton_Click"/>
                                        </CommandBar>
                                    </RelativePanel>
                                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                </Flyout>
                            </Button.Flyout>
```

ListView Implementation;

```
 public class ListViewWithSelectedItems : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        ListViewItem listItem = element as ListViewItem;
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Source = item;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsCheckedInList");
        listItem.SetBinding(ListViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
    }
}
```